# Using XmlLite, cant get the escape sequence &#x8; into the output

Tags: escaping, eml, xmllite

I have data I need to write to an xml file, using xmllite from mfc/c++
I am writing it into the form of a C# DataSet, so the C# consumer can use DatSet.ReadXml()

For valid reasons it contains certain control characters like TAB and BACKSPACE
I replace the backspace with "" as I call WriteElementString
        case '\b':  StrCatW(m_unicodeBuff, L"");       break;

If I populate a DataSet field with a BS character, and use DataSet.WriteXml(), I see the escape sequence in the output
        DEFAULT@/Default//Default=1/

If I read that back in, the DataSet turns it into the BS character

But - when I write the escape sequence using xmlLite, the output contains '&'
        DEFAULT@/Default/&/Default=1/

How can I get xmlLite to output the '&#x8' escape sequence?
BTW - it does the same with other escapes, like TAB, NEWLINE, LINEFEED

Comment: The stackoverflow web site didn't like the escape sequence when surrounded w double quotes
The sequence I am trying to write out is '&#x8', where ever you see empty double quotes

Comment: The stackoverflow site also modified the example of return data - the escape sequence is written out as '&amp;'